# setTranslationY making a white window appear on my fragment container

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a view with some fragments and I created a snackbar with a slide animation on it. The animation works fine, but before it comes up a white window appears where the snackbar is going to appear.

It is happening because I am using setTranslationY on the view. I tried to put the background transparent but it did not work.

How can I solve it?

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
<LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/pager_activity_page"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent">


    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                 android:id="@+id/snackbar_container"
                android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:id="@+id/snackbar_text"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/bpBlue"
            app:tabTextColor="#929292"


            />


</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add you xml please

Comment: Yeah sure! Just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you build your own "snackbar"? Try to use this:

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-snackbar-example/

But your problem:

I think the problem is, that your add your "snackbar" in your linear layout! You set the visibility to "gone" and your bar will not use any space. On your animation you set the visibility to "visible". The linear layout will give you the space, which you need for you bar. You need to add the bar above your layout(also the tablayout)

Comment: That was exactly the problem! I solve it putting a framelayout between the pager and the snackbar! And yeah, I know about the native snackbar of android, but I need to make my own! Thanks!!